# Error code 0x80004005 for Bluetooth Microsoft Mouse connection Windows 7 64

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I have a Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000. It often works just fine but it also routinely loses its connection to the laptop. (Sony Vaio Windows 7 64. I try to reconnect the mouse through Mouse Settings and get error code 0x80004005. Is there a step by step to resolve this? I really appreciate your time and assistance.
Mike

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem after I installed Windows updates but before I restarted. Once I restarted the Bluetooth worked again.